# Why will this code crash? (I am new to C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool checker(int a, int b){
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    if(a % i == 0 && b % i == 0){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

int main(){
int vectorNo;
cin >> vectorNo;
bool foundIt = false;
vector<int> nums;
vector<int> results;
for(int i = 0; i < vectorNo; i++){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    nums.push_back(a);
}

for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++){
        if(j > i){
            if(checker(nums[j], nums[i])){
                foundIt = true;
                results.push_back(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(foundIt){
        foundIt = false;
    }else{
        results.push_back(-1);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
    int thisInt = results[i];
    cout << thisInt << ", ";

}
return 0;
```

}

To me this code seems perfectly fine, although when I try to run it it crashes on me. While console logging, it seems to stop working when I try to run the checker(), inside the if. Specific reason why this happens?

Comment: What is `a % i` when `i` is 0?

Comment: Not the problem, but `for(int j = i + 1)` and the inner if gets obsolete and you don't iterate over half of the array in vain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Loop in `checker`starts with `i=0`, i.e. you do `a% 0` which will result in a  divide by zero exception.